# CodeIgniter - Display HTML DOM using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter as my PHP framework and use jQuery/AJAX to process requests. If I would return data from an AJAX request, and would like to append it to my page with HTML elements on it, where should the HTML elements be included?

In the Model? Where you handle SQL queries.

```
class Item_model extendes CI_Model {

    public function getAll()
    {
        $html = '';
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT col1 FROM table1");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $html .= '<span>'.$row->col1.'</span>'; 
        }
        return json_encode(array('html' => $html));
    }
```

Or in the Controller?

```
class Item extends CI_Controller {

    public function item_list()
    {
        $html = '';
        $data = $this->Item_model->getAll();
        foreach($data as $dataitem){
            $html .= '<span>'.$dataitem['col1'].'</span>';
        }

        echo json_encode(array('html' => $html));

    }
```

Or in the Javascript?

```
success: function(result){

    $.each(result.col1, function(k, v) {
        $("#div").append('<span>'+v+'</span>');
    });

}
```

I've been thinking of the standard/conventional way to do it. But if I have to guess, I would go for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Should be in the Javascript. It will avoid redundant data(span tag) transactions.

Over all process as follows,

Send your ajax request from view to controller, then pass the inputs to the model to do the DB operations and return the DB result array to the controller. Echo the result array after json_encoded.

> view->controller->model->controller->view

---